# How do you use an if/else statement with an ActionSheet?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactionsheet

In my app I'm creating, I have an ActionSheet with some options. When the user selects an option, I want the label to change to what he/she chose. I tried an if/else statement, but I obviously did not create it correctly-

---

```
@IBAction func showActionSheet(sender: AnyObject) {

    var optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Choose a Factor", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)


    let factorActionCageRest = UIAlertAction(title: "Cage Rest", style: .Default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("File Deleted")
    })

    let factorActionAfterSurgery = UIAlertAction(title: "After Surgery", style: .Default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("File Saved")
    })

    let factorActionTrauma = UIAlertAction(title: "Trauma", style: .Default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("File Saved")
    })

    let factorActionSepsis = UIAlertAction(title: "Sepsis", style: .Default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("File Saved")
    })

    let factorActionSevereBurn = UIAlertAction(title: "Severe Burn", style: .Default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("File Saved")
    })

    let factorCancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("Cancelled")
    })


    optionMenu.addAction(factorActionCageRest)
    optionMenu.addAction(factorActionAfterSurgery)
    optionMenu.addAction(factorActionTrauma)
    optionMenu.addAction(factorActionSepsis)
    optionMenu.addAction(factorActionSevereBurn)
    optionMenu.addAction(factorCancelAction)

    if optionMenu.addAction() = factorActionCageRest {
        var factorActionOutput = 1.25
        factorLabel.text = "\(factorActionOutput)"
    }
    self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBOutlet weak var factorLabel: UILabel!
var factorActionOutput = Float()


}
```

---

**Question-** How do I apply an if/else statement to the user's option? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to add custom code for each option then why not add it when defending the UIAlertAction itself.

`let factorActionCageRest = UIAlertAction(title: "Cage Rest", style: .Default, handler: {
 [weak self] (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
 print("File Deleted")
 var factorActionOutput = 1.25
 self?.factorLabel.text = "\(factorActionOutput)"
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your UIAlertAction handler to include the code for changing the label.

```
let factorActionCageRest = UIAlertAction(title: "Cage Rest", style: .Default, handler: {
    [weak self] (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    print("File Deleted")
    let factorActionOutput = 1.25
    self?.factorLabel.text = "\(factorActionOutput)"
})
```

Comment: I followed your answer, and it worked :) The only thing I didn't do is add the '?' after 'self' because it seems to work fine without it.

Answer (score 0):

When the use taps on a button, the `handler` closure for that action is run. If you want something to happen, you would need to add code inside to handler closer to make it happen.

For example, this is how you could change the first action to change the text of `factorLabel` when the button is pressed.

```
let factorActionCageRest = UIAlertAction(title: "Cage Rest", style: .Default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    self.factorLabel.text = "File Deleted"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to change the label and variable when the user selects an option. So you can make use of the `alertAction` for updating the label

```
let factorActionCageRest = UIAlertAction(title: "Cage Rest", style: .Default, handler: {
    (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("File Deleted")
        // Change the label and variable here
})
```